# TableView Index out of range issue

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

My view controller opens a directory, counts the file types therein and stores the results in a dictionary [String:Int] of filetypes and count. I have a TableView that displays this.

The first time I open a directory the ViewController correctly displays the information in the FileTypeTableview. If I try to open another directory, execution gets to the line:

```
let dialogButton = dialog.runModal()
```

Then immediately jumps to a line in my TableView function and throws an index out of range here:

```
val = types[row]
```

Types is a [String] and shows 0 elements and row is an Int and shows 0.
I'm confused by the fact this happens at the dialog.runModal() function call.

Below are the functions that get the directory and display the TableViews.
I'm very new to Swift and MacOS programing and I'd appreciate any insights.

```
@IBAction func getFolder(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let dialog = NSOpenPanel()
    dialog.canChooseDirectories = true
    dialog.canChooseFiles = false
    
    allFiles = []
    fileTypesDict.removeAll()
    
    let dialogButton = dialog.runModal()
    
    if let theURL = dialog.url {
    theDirectory = theURL.path
    allFilesAsPaths = getAllFiles2(atDirectoryPath: theURL.path)
    allFilesAsPaths.sort()
        
    }
    
    fileCountLabel.stringValue = String(allFilesAsPaths.count)
    
    mainTableView2.reloadData()
    fileTypeTableView.reloadData()
}



func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
            
    var numberOfRows : Int = 0
    
    if tableView == mainTableView2 {
        print("number of rows for mainTableView2")
        numberOfRows = allFilesAsPaths.count
    } else if tableView == fileTypeTableView {
        print("number of rows for fileTypeTableView")
        numberOfRows = fileTypesDict.count
    } else if tableView == exifTableView {
        numberOfRows = exifData.count
        print("exifData.count = \(exifData.count)")
        print("number of rows for exifTableview \(numberOfRows)")
    }
    return numberOfRows
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    
    var val : String = ""
    
    if tableView == mainTableView2 {
    val = allFilesAsPaths[row]
    }
    if tableView == exifTableView {
        if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "tag" {
            let tagArray : [String] = Array(exifData.keys)
            val = tagArray[row]
        } else if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "value" {
            let valueArray : [String] = Array(exifData.values)
            val = valueArray[row]
        }
    }
    
    if tableView == fileTypeTableView {

    let types : [String] = Array(fileTypesDict.keys)
    let counts : [Int] = Array(fileTypesDict.values)

    if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "type" {
            val = types[row]
        } else {
            val = String(counts[row])
        }
    }
    return val
}
```

Comment: Try to check if your are making cell when no data is available. In short: when indexpath is more than your arrayList

Comment: Maybe provide more code or describe more precisely what you want to achieve ( The nature of the tables and items ), because it's like you do three different tables with one class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to remove

```
allFiles = []
fileTypesDict.removeAll()
```

And simply set all your arrays at once after dialog validation. Because it looks like presenting the dialog triggers an update of the table, but at this time, your objects are not sync because you do some work before, and after.

BTW, it would be clearer if you do separate table classes than dealing with `if tableView == ... {}`. You take the risk that your code gradually become inextricable. I've been there already ;)

Comment: Thank you – you were right. It seems like that might have been triggering a reload of the TableView. Once moved it seems to be working as expected.

Regarding dealing with multiple TableViews in one class, that was going to be another question I was planning to post. I was wondering how multiple TableViews that are part of the same window should be handled.

Comment: Cool :) It depends of the type of items you display. If your three tables display, for example, the file name, then you make a TableView class that holds an array of `FileItem` with a name property. On `didSet`of this array, you reload the table. All the logic of dispatching the item is outside. You create your three arrays of file objects, then map to file items array and assign it to each items array. This method has an advantage, even if you mess around with file arrays, the items associated to the table are not modified. Not sure I am clear here..

Comment: On the opposite, if your three tables deal with different objects/column names and so, make three different tables and/or tables data sources. Responsibility Segregation is never a bad option in software design.

Comment: I do understand what you're saying about conceptually breaking up the handling of the tableviews that are displaying very different data. I guess I just don't yet understand how to create a new class to serve as a datasource and delegate for tableview(s) – then make the connections. I can create a custom view controller subclass and have it conform to NSTableView protocol but I'm not understanding how to make the storyboard outlet connections to the tableview. (I realize this is very basic stuff and I will search for some relevant tutorials... just haven't found them yet. :-)